phpexcel cell value not showing up in excel file
For a legacy application I have to use PHPExcel and populate an existing Excel file(Excel5 format). A particular cell value starts disappearing in final excel file randomly. File is generated successfully without any errors but employee name is not populated in random rows. I tried it on PHP7.3 and PHP8.2, but same errors persists.
Here is the code I use to populate excel file
require_once dirname(__FILE__). '/../../php/PHPExcel/PHPExcel.php';     
$inputFileName = 'Template.xls';

// Read the existing excel file
$inputFileType = PHPExcel_IOFactory::identify($inputFileName);
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($inputFileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($inputFileName);

// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

$row=3;
for($i=0;$i<count($data);$i++){
            $row++;
            $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()
                        ->setCellValueExplicit('A'.$row, $data[$i]['code'],  PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING)
                        ->setCellValueExplicit('B'.$row, $data[$i]['employee_name'],  PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING)
                        ->setCellValueExplicit('C'.$row, $data[$i]['category_name'],  PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING);
}

If I insert following line in loop then employee name shows up properly in excel file
$data[$i]['employee_name']='123-'.$data[$i]['employee_name'];

If I use 12- then employee name disappears in some rows and if I use 1- then employee_name in some more rows go blank. I also tried with UTF encoding but the result was same. If I add ---* in place of *123- then also employee name goes away. It looks like if and only if I used some numeric prefix to the field only then it gets displayed.
What am I doing wrong, please help.

$row++;  should be after excel code your row number is incremented before writing. if row  = 3 then excel is writing at 4 .

please post  your $data dump output

$row++ is at the right place as per the requirement of template. $data contains multiple rows with each containing indexed values for code, employee_name and category_name.

I tried to replicate as best I could and did not have the same problem so I think your problem may be with the data. Are you able to share some sample data and would also be useful to know what version of PHPPffice/PHPExcel you have. I used php7.4 and PHPExcel version 1.8.2, none of the employee names went away.
